# Is honeypot technique still effective?

Tags: html, forms, spam-prevention, honeypot

I read a lot about honeypots techniques to prevent spam but most of articles I've seen seem to be old.
So I was wondering if nowadays, with all this smart bots, the fact of simply hiding a field with CSS can block them.
Do the bots understand that a field is not shown and they should let it as it is ? And also, do they understand that a field is required or not ?

In others words : **how effective is the honeypot technique ?**

Answer (score 0):

Some bots know about it and has a special routine to identify the honeypot.

Please see this question:

[How effective is the honeypot technique against spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622433/how-effective-is-the-honeypot-technique-against-spam)

And there are more techniques to intensify your guard:

Please see this question:

[How to create a "Nuclear" honeypot to catch form spammers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452716/how-to-create-a-nuclear-honeypot-to-catch-form-spammers?rq=1)